# How to retrieve a return value/object from function and storing in a variable using react-redux?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new to the react-redux environment and have been working on a small project to get acquainted. At the moment, I am working on the login page and have successfully been able to retrieve the response whether successful or not. The problem I face is once I retrieve the response I dont know how to store and read what is in the response without a console.log.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { IsEmpty } from '../../helpers/utils';
import { userActions } from '../../actions/user.actions';

import  LoginLayoutComponent  from '../layouts/loginLayout';

class LoginFormComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Username: '',
            Password: '',
            submitted: false,
            errors: {}
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleValidation = this.handleValidation.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();        

        let response = null;
        let errors = {};
        if (this.handleValidation()) {   

            this.setState({ submitted: true });
            const { Username, Password } = this.state;            

            if (Username && Password) {
                response = JSON.stringify(userActions.login(Username, Password));
                console.log(response);    
                if (response != null) {
                    errors["Error"] = "Invalid Username or Password";
                    this.setState({
                        errors: errors
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    handleValidation() {

        let isValid = true;
        let errors = {};
        if (this.state.submitted === true && IsEmpty(this.state.Username)) {
            errors["Username"] = "Username is required";
            isValid = false;
        }
        if (this.state.submitted === true && IsEmpty(this.state.Password)) {
           errors["Password"] = "Password is required";
            isValid = false;
        }
        this.setState({
            errors: errors
        });
        return isValid;
    }

    render() {

        const { Username, Password, submitted, errors } = this.state;    
        //var errorMessage = loginErrorMessage;

        return (
            <LoginLayoutComponent>
                <div className="panel panel-default">
                    <div className="panel-heading"></div>
                    <div className="panel-body" autoFocus={false}>
                        <form method="post" name="LoginForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <div className='form-group row'>
                                <input className='form-control' type="text" placeholder="Username" name="Username" value={Username} onChange={this.handleChange} autoFocus />                           
                            {!IsEmpty(errors.Username) && <p>{errors.Username}</p>}
                           </div>                    
                            <div className='form-group row' >                           
                                <Input className="form-control" type="Password" placeholder="Password" name="Password" value={Password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                {!IsEmpty(errors.Password) && <p>{errors.Password}</p>}
                            </div>                        
                            <Button className="btn btn-warning btn-block" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Login</Button>                   
                        </form>
                        {!IsEmpty(errors.Response) && <p><b>Login Failed</b>.{errors.Response}</p>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </LoginLayoutComponent>
        );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    //const { loading } = state.authentication;
    return {
    //    loginErrorMessage: state.authentication.error && state.authentication.error.message
    };
}
const LoginForm = connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginFormComponent);
export { LoginForm };
=======================================================================
Action
import { history } from '../helpers/history';
import { userService } from '../services/user.service';
import { userConstants } from '../constants/user.constants';

export const userActions = {
    login,
    logout
};

function login(Username, Password) {

    //return dispatch => {
    console.log('Action begin');
        userService.login(Username, Password)
            .then(
                results => {
                    if (results.username) {
                        console.log('success');  
                        history.push('/home');
                        return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, Username };
                    }                    
            }, error => {    

                        return { error };
                }
            );
    //};   
}
====================================================================
Service
import { HandleResponse, Logout } from '../helpers/utils';


export const userService = {
    login,
    logout,
    _setUserSession
};

function login(Username, Password) {

      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',      
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'            
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify({
            Username,
            Password
        })
    };
    const requestPath = "http://localhost:53986/api/login/postlogin";
    console.log('Start Fetching');
    return fetch(requestPath,requestOptions)
        .then(HandleResponse)
        .then(response => {         

            var result = response && response.results && response.results.length > 0 ? response.results[0] : null;           
            if (result) {
                console.log('Setting session');
                _setUserSession(result);
            }
            return {result};
        }).catch(function (error) {  
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
}

 // Login successful :: store user details 
function _setUserSession(user) {   
    if (user.id) {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));        
    }
}
===========================================
IsEmpty (As requested)

export function IsEmpty(param) {
    return param === null || param === undefined || param === "" || (typeof param === "object" && param.length === 0) || param === false || param === 0;
}
```

The expected result is to have the error displayed in the response and display it on the login form to the user.

Comment: The problem is that errors are not displayed? Can we have the `isEmpty` helper source please?

Comment: Thomas I made that update.

Comment: Oh yes, on the line response = JSON.stringify(userActions.login(Username, Password)); I am attempting to retrieve the response and display it as an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you use promises in both `login` functions.

```
function login(Username, Password) {

    //return dispatch => {
    console.log('Action begin');
        userService.login(Username, Password)
            .then(
                results => {
                    if (results.username) {
                        console.log('success');  
                        history.push('/home');
                        return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, Username };
                    }                    
            }, error => {    

                        return { error };
                }
            );
    //};   
}
```

When you `return` in this function, it returns for the `then` callback but not for the `login` function.

You could fix your functions with es6 [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax (code could be wrong but the idea is here):

```
async function login(Username, Password) {
  try {
    const res = await userService.login(Username, Password);
    if (results.username) {
      console.log('success');  
      history.push('/home');
      return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, Username };
    }         
  } catch (e) {
    return error;
  }                     
}

async function login(Username, Password) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',      
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'            
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify({
      Username,
      Password
    })
  };
  const requestPath = "http://localhost:53986/api/login/postlogin";
  console.log('Start Fetching');
  const response = HandleResponse(await fetch(requestPath,requestOptions));
  const result = response && response.results && response.results.length > 0 ? response.results[0] : null;           
  if (result) {
    console.log('Setting session');
    _setUserSession(result);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: So this works for the most part, but in my API I return OK or bad Request if the Username or password is not found. How will the fetching portion of the code handle a bad result/error?

Comment: I don't know how work your API but, if it doesn't implement a standard error throwing, you have to handle the error in your code with some `if`

Comment: That makes sense